Is there a structure or abstraction that genuinely generalizes both field extensions and (Cohen) forcing?
I'm just starting with the topic so I don't know much. But I'm always told that the similarity with field extensions is just an analogy and we shouldn't take it so seriously.
However, I just must ask if this is so.

One key difference is that any two field extensions of the same field of the same degree are isomorphic, while different forcing extensions of the same ground model for the same forcing notion never are.

@Andres: that is very much not true already for quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$!

@QiaochuYuan Oops. yeah, sorry, of course. I didn't mean that. The analogue of $V[G]$ with $G$ $\mathbb P$-generic for a given $\mathbb P$ is $\mathbb F[\alpha]=\mathbb F(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is a root of a given irreducible polynomial $p$. I compressed too much and wrote nonsense. Anyway :-) if $G_1\ne G_2$ are $\mathbb P$-generic, then $V[G_1]$ and $V[G_2]$ are not isomorphic, while if $p$ is irreducible over $\mathbb F$ and $\alpha_i$ is a root of $p$ in $\mathbb F(\alpha_i)$, $i=1,2$, then $\mathbb F(\alpha_1)$ and $\mathbb F(\alpha_2)$ are isomorphic.

@AndrésE.Caicedo Things get better if we look at the Boolean-valued models rather than picking specific generics, though.

What is the consensus then of this chat?
